# Given two nonempty subsets A and B,

Tags: real-analysis

If A contained in B, and B is bounded above, show that A is also bounded above, and supA ≤ sup B.

I know that supA ≤ b ∈ B but how do I show the first part?

Comment: $\sup(A) \leq b \in B$ is not necessarily true. You could have $A = [0,1]$ and $B = [0,2]$ in which case $\sup(A)>0 \in B$

Comment: That makes sense. Then how do I show that if B is bounded above, so is A?

Comment: Can you edit your post to include your proof of $\sup(A) \leq \sup(B)$? I'm curious how you got that result, because my gut tells me you would first need to show $A$ is bounded above.

Comment: My proof no longer works since sup(A) is not necessarily less than or equal to b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A \subseteq B$ and assume $B$ is bounded above. This means the supremum of $B$ exists. Take $\beta = \sup(B)$. For the sake of contradiction suppose $A$ is not bounded above. Then for any $x \in \Bbb{R}$ we can find $a' \in A$ such that $a'>x$. In particular, we can choose $x = \beta$ which means $a'>\beta$. This implies $a' \notin B$, so $A \not\subseteq B$, a contradiction.

Can you show from here that this implies $\sup(A) \leq \beta \space$?

Comment: Possibly....if A is now bounded above this means supA ≤ any upper bound of B, in particular the least upper bound, so supA≤supB?

Comment: @user141447 sounds good to me! You have the idea. I personally would write "$a \leq \beta$ for all $a \in A$ as shown in the proof by contradiction so $\beta$ is an upper bound of $A$. Hence, $\sup(A) \leq \beta$"

Answer (score 0):

Here's a formal proof:

$B$ is bounded from above $\Rightarrow \exists \sup B$

by definition, $\sup B \geq \forall x \in B$ (1)

$A \subseteq B$, therefore $\forall x \in A \Rightarrow$ $x \in B$ (2)

(1) & (2) $\Rightarrow \sup B \geq \forall x \in A \Rightarrow$ A is bounded from above by $\sup B$ (3)

$\sup A = \min M$, where $M:=\{y \in \mathbb R|y \geq \forall x \in A\}$ (4)

(3) $\Rightarrow \sup B \in M$ (5)

(4) & (5) $\Rightarrow \sup B \geq \sup A$